# Get formcontrolname of FormGroup in an FormArray

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, formarray

I have a `FormGroup` with a `FormArray` that has 3 `FormControls`. I want to iterate trough the `FormArray` and display the values of each one in a form. But I'm stuck on what to put on the `FormControlName`.

This is my `FormGroup`:

```
fg: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    properties: new FormArray([])
  });
```

This is how I add the `FormControls` into my `FormArray`,`dataArray` is the data I get from my response:

```
let formArray = this.fg.get('properties') as FormArray;
    for(let property of dataArray){
      const userPropertyGroup = new FormGroup({
        user_id: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
        name: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
        value: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      });

      formArray.push(userPropertyGroup);
```

To set the values in the `FormArray`:

```
 for(let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++ ){
      formArray.controls[i].setValue({
          user_id: dataArray[i].user_id,
          name: dataArray[i].name,
          value: dataArray[i].value,
        })
    }
```

Now I want to iterate and display all the values in the form. With `{{property.value.name}}` I'm able to get the values of each property of the array but I'm stuck at the `formControlName`. What should go there?

```
 <form [formGroup]="fg" >
    <table *ngFor="let property of fg.get('properties')['controls']" class="full-width">
        {{property.value.name}}
      <tr>
        <td>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput formControlName="?????" placeholder="User id">
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
```

I checked a lot of similar questions at StackOverflow but none of them helps. I also tried implementing this [example from Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName).  Any help is really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a stackBlitz for this?

Comment: I have never done that before but I will try and post it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to structure your html as below:

```html
<form [formGroup]="fg">
  <ng-container formArrayName="properties">
    <div *ngFor="let property of properties.controls; let i = index"> <!-- Iterate over FormArray controls -->
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="i"> <!-- Since each control within FormArray is a FormGroup -->
          <input formControlName="user_id" type="text" />
          <input formControlName="name" type="text" />
          <input formControlName="value" type="text" />
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Define a getter within your `ts` component file to get the properties FormArray:

```ts
get properties(): FormArray {
  return this.fg.get('properties') as FormArray;
}
```

**PS:** I haven't specified any CSS classes or Angular Material components in HTML, to keep the structure simple, so that it's easy to understand the hierarchy. Also I have used `ng-container`, you can use elements as per your use case.

Comment: thank you so much! This works! I have been looking for this for the whole day! Thank you again!! Can't upvote or anything because I don't have enough reputation.